# Windows 7: Full usage of one CPU core by WmiPreSE for several seconds after resume or network changes

Tags: windows-7, networking, cpu-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does WMI Provider Host ( WmiPrvSE.exe ) keep spiking my CPU ?](https://superuser.com/questions/240794/why-does-wmi-provider-host-wmiprvse-exe-keep-spiking-my-cpu)

Every time my computer resumes from sleep, connects to a network, or disconnects from a network, one CPU core is fully utilized for several seconds by a system network process "WmiPreSE.exe".  What is the purpose of this process and what is it doing that requires this CPU usage?  The system is running Windows 7 Home Premium x64 Service Pack 1 and has a quad-core AMD Phenom II N930 processor at 2.0 GHz.

**Edit:** The system is a custom-built HP Pavilion dv6z-3000 Select Edtion laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a core Windows component.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx) You may or may not have something that actually relies on it but it's normal for it to throttle on connecting to or disconnecting from a network.  (This happens when you wake the machine up so that isn't really a separate scenario.)  If it bothers you that much, you can try disabling the Windows Management Instrumentation service, but I wouldn't recommend it since it might break something, and I seriously doubt this is actually harming your experience with the machine.

Comment: What is the purpose of the CPU usage anyway?  What is WMI actually trying to do?

Comment: Presumably enumerating the machines it sees on the network and deciding if it needs to do anything with them, but I'm conjecturing.  There are tons of system processes that spike CPU momentarily when they kick in so this isn't really unusual; they're designed to do their thing fast and get the hell out of the way.