# How do I get wmiprvse.exe to stop hogging my CPU?

Tags: windows-7

I did a roll back on my Windows 7 OS and that got rid of it but its come back. I tried running the Microsoft hotfix (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1157)

> Not enough storage space is available to process this command.

... was the answer.

Is there another solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does WMI Provider Host (WmiPrvSE.exe) keep spiking my CPU?](http://superuser.com/questions/240794/why-does-wmi-provider-host-wmiprvse-exe-keep-spiking-my-cpu)

Comment: The hotfix you mention is not for Windows 7.  The WMI service being busy could be caused by quite a few things. Try disabling things with MSConfig and unplugging devices.  Check out the question I marked as a possible duplicate for testing measures you can take. Then perhaps come back and update this question with additional, applicable information (like what you've tried and what you've found) so that we can help you narrow it down.

Comment: @techie007 I lost interest in the question you linked to because it seemed to only be relevant to HP computers. However one of the answers has a link to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wmi/archive/2009/05/27/is-wmiprvse-a-real-villain.aspx which helped me find that a mail server I'd installed was the problem. After stopping the services my CPU is averaging about 30% instead of the usual 100%! :) So thanks very much and I'm sorry that you felt the need to edit my question. I'm sure you can appreciate how frustrating such issues can be.