# WmiPrvSE excess cpu on Windows 7 32bit

Tags: windows-7, cpu, wmi, threads, csrss.exe

One of my desktops is running Windows 7 (32bit). I am seeing unexpectedly high CPU load for the WmiPrvSE process. Using ProcessExplorer, I can see that it is just one thread that is alternately ranging from 4-15% cpu on an otherwise-idle machine. That thread is entitled ntdll.dll!RtlRegisterThreadWithCsrss. The thrashing is periodic with approximately a five second cycle, with only a brief instant between elevated cpu levels.

Interestingly, when I attempt to invoke csrss.exe manually, I get a dialog box informing me that it can't run in 32 bit mode. Nevertheless, it IS present in the process tree.

So, it appears to me that I have a thread thrashing to interact with something that may or may not be available. What am I missing? Any clues? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I posted an "how to" [answer on how you can trace the cause](https://superuser.com/a/949470/174557)

Comment: The other thread offered a wealth of suggestions; the recipe didn't work for me directly, but ultimately -- via ProcMon -- I found that my culprit was CCleaner's /monitor mode. Now my idle PC just spends a couple percent of the cpu on the process explorer in lieu of the task manager..

Comment: ok, post an answer to the other topic with all steps you did (with some pictures) to show how you traced your issue.