# WMI provider host high CPU load

Tags: cpu-usage, wmi

I know there are plenty of posts about that issue, and I have read them. All the suggests boil down to:

1. Rebuilding WMI Repository - I checked and winmgmt reports that the repository is consistent
2. Checking in the event viewer which processes cause WMI errors - I have, and pretty much all these processes do not exist anymore by the time I look them up

Other ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does WMI Provider Host (WmiPrvSE.exe) keep spiking my CPU?](https://superuser.com/questions/240794/why-does-wmi-provider-host-wmiprvse-exe-keep-spiking-my-cpu)

Comment: Very partially. I'm not using HP...

Comment: Could you specify (by editing your question) what is "high CPU" with an actual number? And does it stay like that for a long period, or is it a spike? In my case "WMI Provider Host" in Task Manager jumps up and down around 10% for a long time (i.e. it's the normal) and on my Dell laptop that's enough to keep the CPU fans in helicopter mode as I call it, and the constant noise is really annoying. Thinking of opening another question, unless your problem is the same. What I mean is, people who have over 50% CPU usage might have a different issue or approach to solving it.

Comment: My current solution is to restart Windows, sometimes more than once, until I hit the jackpot of WMI sitting at less than 2% most of the time, which keeps the fans off. But obviously this is not ideal...